# Accessing labels outside of the declared program AREA in ARM Assembler

Tags: assembly, arm

Hi I've started learning ARM Assembler (Version 4T Instruction Set) from William Pohl's book on the subject and have been trying to solve some of the small programming problems described there. However I've become slightly stuck as to how to access some data stored at labelled points in the program but in another AREA of the program. An abbreviated example of the code looks like this:

```
AREA Main, CODE, READONLY
ENTRY

main
LDR R0, =list_elements
LDR R1, =list_length

... Some more code ...

ALIGN
AREA ListData, DATA, READWRITE

list_length
DCW 0x2

list_data
DCW 0x081, 0x1da

END
```

The problem comes that when I run this R0 and R1 get loaded with the value 0x40000000 and 0x40000004 respectively. I know from the memory map that 0x40000000 is the first address of User Writeable RAM and the offset between the two is correct but the actual data values are in a completely different memory location. Does anyone know how to rectify this?

I've had a look through the documentation and came across [this](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_Bgbbfgia.htm) and specifically Example 12. This seems to be exactly what I want to do but my code performs completely differently to my expectations or so it seems. Am I simply using the instructions wrong or is there something else I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: _"but the actual data values are in a completely different memory location"_ Which location would that be? Do you have any code in your crt0 (startup) code to initialize the READWRITE data?

Comment: It comes directly 'next to' the instructions in memory, so the instructions stop at address 0x4B or thereabouts there is some space and then the data starts in address 0x54. No not at present, from what I'd read I'd assumed there was no need though having looked back over examples in the book they include all the data in a code block so I've obviously missed something

Comment: Typically in the startup code you would have something like `ldr r1, =__data_lma / ldr r2, =__data_start / ldr r4, =__data_end / bl Copy`. Those symbols (`__data_start` etc) would come from the linker script. There'd also be code to clear the `bss` (uninitialized data) section, set up the stack, and some other stuff.

Comment: Ok thanks that's good to know, I need to look into the start up scripts more then, any links/tutorials I could look at?

Comment: the linker will resolve labels with or without entries in the script, ldr r1,=label; ldr r0,[r1]  and then label can be anywhere.

Comment: It is helpful if you are clear about what tools you are using.  The `AREA` and other operations are not *assembler*.  They are *pseudo-ops* and can be different for every assembler.  Also, this particular question involves the linker.  You should generate a map file.  You question also says `R1` has 0x40000004, but I see `R4` in the assembler?  How have you called the linker, etc is important.

Comment: That was a mistake I've now changed it. I'm using the Kiel uVision4 MDK toolchain. Really sorry about the other questions I'm honestly not sure I'm really new to all this stuff

Answer (score -2):

start.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    b reset

reset:
    mov sp,#0x8000

    ldr r1,=label0
    ldr r0,[r1]
    ldr r1,label1_addr
    ldr r2,[r1]
    bl otherfun
hang: b hang

label1_addr: .word label1
```

other.s

```
.globl otherfun
otherfun:
    bx lr

.globl label0
label0: .word 0x1234
.globl label1
label1: .word 0xABCDEF
```

memmap (linker script)

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
}
```

Makefile

```
ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi

COPS = -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding 

all : start.elf

clean :
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list

start.o : start.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as start.s -o start.o

other.o : other.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as other.s -o other.o

start.elf : memmap start.o other.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld start.o other.o -T memmap -o start.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D start.elf > start.list
```

output start.list

```
start.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   eaffffff    b   8004 <reset>

00008004 <reset>:
    8004:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8008:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 8024 <label1_addr+0x4>
    800c:   e5910000    ldr r0, [r1]
    8010:   e59f1008    ldr r1, [pc, #8]    ; 8020 <label1_addr>
    8014:   e5912000    ldr r2, [r1]
    8018:   eb000002    bl  8028 <otherfun>

0000801c <hang>:
    801c:   eafffffe    b   801c <hang>

00008020 <label1_addr>:
    8020:   00008030    andeq   r8, r0, r0, lsr r0
    8024:   0000802c    andeq   r8, r0, ip, lsr #32

00008028 <otherfun>:
    8028:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000802c <label0>:
    802c:   00001234    andeq   r1, r0, r4, lsr r2

00008030 <label1>:
    8030:   00abcdef    adceq   ip, fp, pc, ror #27
```

so this

```
 ldr r1,=label0
```

means I want to load the address of label0 into r1, but since we cant resolve label0 at assemble time the linker has to fill in addresses later, the assembler has to reserve a memory location in .text and generate a pc relative load.  Which it does.  what is eventually address 0x8020 is where the assembler is keeping the address to label0 for start.o

if you want to explicitly control where that word is located in .text and not let the assembler try to find a place then you use code like this

```
    ldr r1,label1_addr
...
label1_addr: .word label1
```

label1_addr can be thought of as a local variable, the instruction is resolved as a pc relative load, but you control where label1_addr lives within the code.

label1 and label0 are just labels which means they are just addresses so at the end of the label1_addr line you dont say =label1 you say label1 here, I know that is confusing.

I specifically kept the label0 and label1 global addresses in a separately assembled object to force them to be external and resolved by the linker.  And that is exactly what happened the linker placed start.o and then other.o in the binary because that is the order they were on the command line and the linker script didnt interfere with that order.  So we see the start.o code then other.o code and the addresses for label0 and label1 are resolved into the locations setup by the assembly of start.s.

Clearly I am using a different assembler/syntax than you are using.  You typically dont need area, proc, .function, etc.  Assembler specific stuff that may or may not help you depending on what you are doing (certainly makes it less portable).  gnu assembler (gas) allows for .globl or .global to declare something global which you have to do for someone else to be able to get the linker to resolve that label.  But for gas externs dont have to be declared you simply use a name and if it is not resolved in that assembly step (file+includes) then it is automatically an extern.

Comment: This code is for the *GNU* tools, but he used ARM tool specific assembler.  For instance, `gas` has no `AREA` keyword?